# Is it possible to calculate the standard deviation without the samples?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

Imagine I had two sets of samples. The only information I have about them is their

- Size
- Average
- Standard deviation

Is it possible to calculate the standard deviation of a third set that is composed by the union of all samples in both sets?
And what if the original sets had the same size?

Comment: I suggest changing "sum" to "union" to make the question more readable. "Sum" had me confused for a moment.

Comment: It may help your web search to look for "pooling" of samples, "pooled samples" or "pooled populations", and especially "pooled standard deviation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  The equation should be in your book, or you can look at [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) under the heading Population-based statistics

Answer (score 0):

As Ross suggested, from Wikipedia:

Standard deviations of non-overlapping (X ∩ Y = ∅) sub-populations can be aggregated as follows if the size (actual or relative to one another) and means of each are known:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/9/5/1/951ab01cabd025deadd5bf497bae971f.png